# Database migration Checklist

Tags: sql

Can someone p[lease provide me with the checklist in moving database from one server to another server.

Comment: You can get a backup of the database and restore on another server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Analyze the disk space of the target server for the new database, if the disk space is not enough add more space on the target server
2. Confirm the data and log file location for the target server
3. Collect the information about the Database properties (Auto Stats, DB Owner, Recovery Model, Compatibility level, Trustworthy option etc)
4. Collect the information of dependent applications, make sure application services will be stopped during the database migration
5. Collect the information of database logins, users and their permissions. (Optional)
6. Check the database for the Orphan users if any
7. Check the SQL Server for any dependent objects (SQL Agent Jobs and Linked Servers)
8. Check, if the database is part of any maintenance plan